# My framerate in Feed The Beast: Endeavour is awful, even though my PC is good. What can I do about this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast, performance

I have a decent enough PC (8 GB of RAM, i5 6600K, Radeon RX 570) that should be able to handle Feed The Beast: Endeavour fine, but my FPS jumps around between 5 to 10 FPS. What can I do about this?

Comment: Just my opinion, and I’m not trying to be rude (my computer has very comparable specs) but I don’t know if these days those specs are exceptionally good, especially for modded Minecraft, which can get pretty hard you your computer pretty fast.

Comment: I agree with Topcode. When I had a PC equipped with a i7 6800k, 16GB of RAM, and a GTX 1070, I was only able to get 30 to 40 fps with FTB/heavily modded Minecraft. That PC specs is, sadly, not decent enough.

Comment: This is not an answer on it's own, but make sure you don't over allocate memory. Go with the amount the pack recommends. Giving a pack 16GB of memory, if all it needs is 4GB can lead to problems, such a micro-stutters.

Comment: @Topcode I wrote the question as if it was my perspective just to make it sound good, but in reality what happened was that I was going to play FTB with my girlfriend, and her PC (the one which specs are written here), had this atrocious performance. This despite that my PC, which is older and has overall slower hardware, had good performance. So while you may have a point, I don't think it makes my question invalid. My PC gets a stable 60 FPS in FTB apart from occasional hitches which I can live with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting Mipmap Levels to OFF in instead of 4 which the default value is. This increased my performance from around 5 to 10 FPS to around 80 FPS.

[image]

I'm not sure why this helps exactly, but looking around the Internet I'm far from the only one to have had this resolve FPS problems in Feed The Beast on otherwise powerful hardware.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a lack of RAM. Mipmaps increase RAM consumption for textures by about 33%, and 8 GB of RAM is not a lot nowadays. Mipmaps shouldn't affect performance all that much, but if your PC is running out of RAM, this can severely impact your performance, which is exactly what seems to have happened here.

Comment: minor point: mimapping will consume more *gpu* memory, not system memory. Looks like RX 570 reference boards were 4 or 6 GB (?)

Comment: @Nolonar For whatever reason, mipmapping in Minecraft leads to horrible performance on some computers, even with plenty of RAM and VRAM. 3D games are still arcane art :D

Answer (score 0):

Especially in modded Minecraft, reducing particle counts can improve CPU performance dramatically. Even though Minecraft is now a AAA title, it still uses the CPU to calculate particle physics, and with a single core! As if this is not bad enough, there is no [culling](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2021/Scene/Frustum-Culling) that's done with this, meaning that all particles are taking physics computations all the time.

In short, reducing particles to minimal, or better none will get rid of a lot of client-side calculations, and as a result boost your FPS by a significant margin.